# Is there any android location service concurrency on running apps?

Tags: android, gps, location

If I'm using Google Maps to navigate trough a route and then start my app that uses android.location services requesting locations updates continually (GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER every 7 seconds). Will my app and Google Maps compete each other for GPS hardware service or will they share the locations?
Remembering that I'm using android.location services, not Google Play Services